# Is there a way to extend an entity framework object so that it doesn't map to the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, partial-classes

I have an entity framework object that someone else created that maps to a database.  I want to extend this object to include fields that I don't want to map to the database (or create new tables or fields in the database)  I've been told you can mark a field as [NotMapped] and it won't map to the database.  I've been looking into partial classes, and I was wondering if there is a way to create partial classes where one would map to the database and the other wouldn't, instead of marking everything individually as [NotMapped].

Comment: Why not simply create dto class and map your data between that dto and model class?

Comment: `[NotMapped]` is exactly how you'd do this.  Or if you're using the fluent syntax for mapping, you'd use the `.Ignore()` method in that syntax.  Is there a reason you *don't* want to use the attribute that's designed for this?

Comment: I just wondered if there was a shorthand way so I wouldn't have to mark each field individually since I might end up with a lot of fields that don't map.  This way works just fine.  I just wondered if there was an easier or cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the compiler is concerned: all it does is stitch together the various different `partial` classes end-to-end. There isn't much you can do at a file-by-file (etc) level, except perhaps change the `using` directives at the top of the page, but that *doesn't change what the code means*.

So basically: no, there is no way to do what you describe using `partial` classes. You would need to decorate each member separately, as you are already doing.